# No Persistence provider for EntityManager named fooBar

Tags: hibernate, rest, jersey, entity

**UPDATE:** I have solved the problem, by adding the jars one by one to the class path and debugging it. I had 2 jars confronting with eachother. The jars were related to REST.

I am getting this exception when I am trying to start the webapp:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named fooBar
```

I am using REST and Hibernate, I have the following persistance xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">

<persistence-unit name="fooBar" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

    <class>whateverpackage.Users</class>
    <class>whateverpackage.Messages</class>

    <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode> 

    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Test2?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="password" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory" />

    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

I am using the latest Jersey and Hibernate, those are added to the classpath. The META-INF folder including the persistence.xml are in the src folder of the project.

- Jersey JAX-RS 2.1 RI bundle
- Hibernate 5.2.10.Final
- Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M21
- java version 1.8.0_121

I have the following jars in the classpath:

- antlr-2.7.7.jar
- aopalliance-repackaged-2.5.0-b42.jar
- cdi-api-1.1.jar
- classmate-1.3.0.jar
- commons-io-2.5.jar
- dom4j-1.6.1.jar
- el-api-2.2.jar
- gson-2.2.2.jar
- hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar
- hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar
- hibernate-entitymanager-5.2.10.Final.jar
- hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
- hk2-api-2.5.0-b42.jar
- hk2-locator-2.5.0-b42.jar
- hk2-utils-2.5.0-b42.jar
- jackson-annotations-2.8.8.jar
- jackson-core-2.8.8.jar
- jackson-databind-2.8.8.jar
- jandex-2.0.3.Final.jar
- java-json.jar
- javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar
- javassist-3.22.0-CR2.jar
- javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar
- javax.inject-1.jar
- javax.inject-2.5.0-b42.jar
- javax.json-1.1.jar
- javax.json-api-1.1.jar
- javax.json.bind-api-1.0.jar
- javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar
- javax.ws.rs-api-2.1-m09.jar
- jaxb-api-2.2.7.jar
- jboss-interceptors-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Beta1.jar
- jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar
- jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar
- jersey-client.jar
- jersey-common.jar
- jersey-container-servlet-core.jar
- jersey-container-servlet.jar
- jersey-hk2.jar
- jersey-media-jaxb.jar
- jersey-media-json-binding.jar
- jersey-media-sse.jar
- jersey-server.jar
- json-simple-1.1.1.jar
- jsr250-api-1.0.jar
- jstl-1.2.jar
- jtds-1.2.2.jar
- mysql-connector-java-5.1.43-bin.jar
- org.osgi.core-4.2.0.jar
- osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar
- persistence-api-1.0.jar
- validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
- yasson-1.0.jar

Comment: What hibernate jar did you put in your class path? `hibernate-entitymanager.jar` or `hibernate-core.jar`

Comment: Check if `org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence` is available, and look for caused by in your stack trace. I think you might need to change the persistence provider to `org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider`

Comment: I have both of them:

hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar
hibernate-entitymanager-5.2.10.Final.jar


I've tried to change the providier in the persistence.xml and I got the following error (I am sorry for the pastebin link, it was too much character too insert): https://pastebin.com/Agrtb9ML

Comment: Are you sure that your `persistence.xml` is located in `src\main\java\META-INF\persistence.xml` ?

Comment: Yes Rouliboy , I have just check it. By the Way, I have added again the jars by jar by jar, and now the previously mentioned error message is gone, now im getting the following:

 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.client.RxInvokerProvider


Update: now the RxInvokerProvider exception is gone too, I'm getting NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers